# do I need to have different application extension for app publishing on google webstore?

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I have a Question that does the application developed to publish on google web store needs different extensions for Mac and PC ?

If anyone knows the answer and give me some links for the documentation which describes the answer then that would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a question about how to get started in the Chrome Web Store and perhaps publishing your first extension or app.

The answer to your question is no, you will only need a single format. You upload a single file, a zip file, to your Chrome Web Store Developer Panel and it will be available for both Windows and Mac users for download/installation to their Chrome browsers.

Here is Google's Getting Started Guide: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question to you is that is it possible to publish the app on google web store and have the application access to the limited user with authentication ? I mean if I have an app on web store and I dont want that app to be visible to the world but selected user will be able to see that with proper authentication ? is that possible and if yes then how ?

Comment: When you create a listing for your app, you will see a list of desired publication scopes. You will have the option to only publish to a select set of user's identified by emails you list, or just users who have a link to the application. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Steve, One more question I have regarding to the private app on google web store. Let me explain my scenario, I need to have an extension app on google store which will not be visible to anyone else. Only selected user who has my company's website access with the authentication will be able to see the download option. they need to authenticate themselves with their credentials and then they will be able to download the extension from webstore. Do then need to login into google group to download the extension?